# React native elevation increases as going to bottom

Tags: react-native

This is the code I used for the elevation

```
                <View
                    style={[
                    {
                    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
                    width: 30,
                    height: 30,
                    borderRadius: 15,

                    shadowColor: '#000',
                    shadowOffset: {
                        width: 0,
                        height: 2,
                    },
                    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
                    shadowRadius: 3.84,
                    elevation: 5,
                    },
                    ]}
                >
```

[Image of shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAr1Z.png)

You can clearly see the difference between these shadows.

I am using the same component multiple time in scrollView as below:-

[The Image of my scrollView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PIBU.png)

Comment: try using this generator and play with the style https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/

Comment: yes, I used it in this scrollView.But the error is the same.